# Make simple POST-Requests with Powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, post

I searched the whole web but I guess I overlook something simple.

I want to send a FORM with the Keys "Foo" and the Value "Bar" as POST to URL "api.foobar.com".

In Python I could have done it in 2 Minutes but I am new to PowerShell and want to learn it. So maybe someone can help me.

edit:

I tried the following:

```
$Body = @{
    Foo = 'Bar'
 }
 Invoke-WebRequest 'http://api.foobar.com' -Body $Body -Method 
 'POST'
```

and the API answers "Value Foo is missing". The API expects "Foo" als key and "Bar" is the value. The response of the API is JSON.

Comment: If you've searched the whole web then you definitely overlooked something :) Give [`Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) a try

Comment: Yeah. I tried every hint I found and it didn't work as expected. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Where do I put the Key and where the value of the Key?

Answer (score 1):

If the query should or can be JSON try something like:

```
    $JSONQuery = '
    {
        "Foo":"Bar"
    }'
    Invoke-WebRequest 'http://api.foobar.com' -Body $JSONQuery -Method 'POST' -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).